# How can I write columns containing positive and negative numbers aligned by first numerical digit in bash

Tags: bash, sorting, awk, sed, sh

While working with a data file containing columns of positive and negative numbers, I came up with aligning the columns using `column -t`. However, this aligns columns with treating the -ve sign as a field and this does not look nice. Is there any way (even within `column`) to treat it differently?

*EDIT:*
A real-case scenario does not need to have the same number of numerical digits and many contain many columns.
A toy example is as follows:

cat input.txt

```
-1.5647453E-09 1.33356715E-09
1.3224229E-09 4.8350685E-09
1.7098133E-09 -2.8287697E-10
-3.3301262E-09 -1.8597501E-08
```

With `column -t`:

```
-1.5647453E-09  1.33356715E-09
1.3224229E-09   4.8350685E-09
1.7098133E-09   -2.8287697E-10
-3.3301262E-09  -1.8597501E-08
```

Expected:

```
-1.5647453E-09   1.33356715E-09
 1.3224229E-09   4.8350685E-09
 1.7098133E-09  -2.8287697E-10
-3.3301262E-09  -1.8597501E-08
```

Basically, I want to align it from the left (with the first numerical digits) for each column so that it looks as above.
Note that `column -t` aligns it from the left but also takes -ve sign which is undesired.

Comment: You should have included a 3rd column of just `1`s or other simplem consistent number in your sample input/output as you're getting answers that won't work if some earlier values are longer than others as is the case with the 1st value in your 2nd column.

Answer (score 5):

Assumptions:

- all values have the same max width (including `-`) of 14 characters
- all lines have 2 columns

A simple right-justified `printf` format should suffice, eg, using `awk/printf`:

```
$ awk '{printf "%14s  %14s\n",$1,$2}' file
-1.5647453E-09   1.3335671E-09
 1.3224229E-09   4.8350685E-09
 1.7098133E-09  -2.8287697E-10
-3.3301262E-09  -1.8597501E-08
```

---

Assumptions:

- all values have the same max width (including `-`) of 14 characters
- lines have a variable number of columns

Sample data:

```
$ cat file
-1.5647453E-09 1.3335671E-09  4.8350685E-09
1.3224229E-09 4.8350685E-09  -4.8350685E-09  4.8350685E-09
1.7098133E-09 -2.8287697E-10    -2.8287697E-10
-3.3301262E-09 -1.8597501E-08  1.7098133E-09
```

Expanding on the previous `awk` example to deal with a variable number of columns:

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s%14s", (i==1 ? "" : "  "), $i; print ""}' file
```

This generates:

```
-1.5647453E-09   1.3335671E-09   4.8350685E-09
 1.3224229E-09   4.8350685E-09  -4.8350685E-09   4.8350685E-09
 1.7098133E-09  -2.8287697E-10  -2.8287697E-10
-3.3301262E-09  -1.8597501E-08   1.7098133E-09
```

---

If the widths of the fields can vary and/or columns need to be aligned differently (eg, decimal-aligned), it would be possible to expand the `awk` code as needed ... but at this point I'd recommend asking a new question, making sure to provide details and a more representative sample set of data.

Comment: Nice solution for this toy example. The assumptions are strong though.

Comment: Probably I should have mentioned this as a toy example. I wanted something along the line of `column` which does not care about how many columns we have etc.

Answer (score 3):

Using GNU or BSD sed for `-E`:

```
$ sed -E 's/(^| )([0-9])/\1+\2/g' file | column -t | sed 's/+/ /g'
-1.5647453E-09   1.33356715E-09
 1.3224229E-09   4.8350685E-09
 1.7098133E-09  -2.8287697E-10
-3.3301262E-09  -1.8597501E-08
```

or using any sed:

```
$ sed 's/^\([0-9]\)/+\1/; s/ \([0-9]\)/ +\1/g' file | column -t | sed 's/+/ /g'
-1.5647453E-09   1.33356715E-09
 1.3224229E-09   4.8350685E-09
 1.7098133E-09  -2.8287697E-10
-3.3301262E-09  -1.8597501E-08
```

or the GNU/BSD way if your `column` has the `-s` option (I assume you can tweak the "any sed" one similarly):

```
$ sed -E 's/ /\t/g; s/(^|\t)([0-9])/\1 \2/g' file | column -s$'\t' -t
-1.5647453E-09   1.33356715E-09
 1.3224229E-09   4.8350685E-09
 1.7098133E-09  -2.8287697E-10
-3.3301262E-09  -1.8597501E-08
```

---

Previous answer given previous sample input/output:

If your `column` has a `-R` option:

```
$ column -t -R1,2 file
-1.5647453E-09   1.3335671E-09
 1.3224229E-09   4.8350685E-09
 1.7098133E-09  -2.8287697E-10
-3.3301262E-09  -1.8597501E-08
```

Some versions of `column` support `-R0` to right-align all columns, see https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/issues/1306.

Comment: My `column` does not contain `-R` option.

Comment: The version used by other people reading this in future might so it's still useful.

Comment: This is weird since I can not find it using `column --version` or `column -V`. `column --help` does not work either. This is Linux Mint 20.2.  Only way I see something is `man column` which shows a date BSD July 29, 2004.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it since given the new sample input/output in your question you aren't looking to right-align the data either so `-R` wouldn't work for you anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/(^(-[0-9]\.[^ ]*)|^([0-9]+\.[^ ]*))? ((-[0-9]\.[^ ]*)|([0-9]+\.[^ ]*))/\2 \3\t\5 \6/g' input_file
-1.5647453E-09   1.33356715E-09
 1.3224229E-09   4.8350685E-09
 1.7098133E-09  -2.8287697E-10
-3.3301262E-09  -1.8597501E-08
```

Comment: While that would produce the posted expected output from the posted sample input, it wouldn't work in general because some values are longer than others, e.g. try adding a 3rd column of just `1`s to the sample input then run that command and you'll see that the values in that 3rd column don't line up.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/\S+/ &/g;s/ -/-/g' file
```

Prepend a space to any non-space string.

Remove a space before  a `-`.

Comment: While that would produce the posted expected output from the posted sample input, it wouldn't work in general because some values are longer than others, e.g. try adding a 3rd column of just `1`s to the sample input then run that command and you'll see that the values in that 3rd column don't line up.

Answer (score 1):

Execute `printf` inside `sed`

```bash
sed 's/[^[:blank:]]\+/printf " % E" &/e' input.txt
```

Explanation:

- `s/regexp/command/e` apply `command` for each match of `regexp`. Here, `command` is not a *sed command*, this is a *system command* which is piped by `sed` into the pattern space.
- `[^[:blank:]]\+` matches each *number* separated by whitespaces or tabs.
- For each *number* mached (`&`), apply format `" % E"`

  - The space *after* `%` add *a space* before each **positive** number.
  - The space *before* `%` separates each formatted number from another on *stdout*.
  - By using *type conversion* `%E` or `%e`, each *double* number is rounded and converted in the style `[-]d.dddE±dd` or `[-]d.ddde±dd` respectively. The exponent always contains at least two digits.
  - We can change the default *width* (13) and *precision* (6) on stdout: `printf " % 20.10E" ...`

> It is worth noting that other proposals could fail in more general contexts. The `input2.txt` file contains valid decimals, but we get correct format only with this proposal.

```bash
$ cat input2.txt 
-17.5647453E-09 174.343356899415E-09
1.322E-09 4.8350545454685E-09
1756.708133E-09 -21.85297E-10
-32.3888301262E-09 -145454.01E-08
```

```bash
$ sed 's/[^[:blank:]]\+/printf " % E" &/e' input2.txt 
 -1.756475E-08  1.743434E-07
  1.322000E-09  4.835055E-09
  1.756708E-06 -2.185297E-09
 -3.238883E-08 -1.454540E-03
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples only, please try following `awk` solution.

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '{$1=$1;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i!~/^-/){$i=FS $i}}} 1' Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of above solution:

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '
{
  $1=$1
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i!~/^-/){ $i=FS $i }
  }
}
1
' Input_file
```